# i want know why add_execuable sometimes can use the name diffent whit project name, and somtimes not

Tags: cmake

i want use cmake to build my project.but i have some question about add_execuable function.
when i use add_execuable to build a project not use the project name.there are some problem.
it looks like the cmake can't understand the relative path.
there are two cmakelist.txt. i want know why one is work.and another can't work.

```
Set(SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)

# Add an executable
#add_executable(hello main.cpp)
add_executable(hello ${SOURES})
```

this can't work

```
Set(SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)

# Add an executable
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
```

this can work
and there are project name

```
# Set the project name
project (hello_cmake)
```

my english is so bad, so sorry =_=

Comment: Description "there are some problem" is not very useful. What error message do you get? As you are new on Stack Overflow, you may find helpful [ask] article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's complaining that it can't find `main.cpp` then it's an issue with your paths. If the `CMakeLists.txt` containing the `add_executable()` statement is in the same directory as `main.cpp` then you shouldn't have any problems as it will look relative to the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

If there are any spaces in the path then that could cause problems as well. In that case you'd need to use `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp`.

Comment: this answer help me to fix the bug.it look like flle(source /main.cpp) this code cant work.but in add_executable(),it can add the main.cpp file.it was a file path problem.and ,thx :D